# How to dispaly random questions with their options on web page using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually , I want to display some random questions from database (mysql) in web page where user can answer that question by using radio buttons

here is my code to display data in web page using php

```
public function loadQuestions() {
   try {
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions');
       $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt;
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And i called that function from my displaying page (quiz.php)

```
  $stmt = $auth_user->loadQuestions(); 

    <form action="#">
          <!-- this backend logic -->
            <?php 
                 foreach($stmt as $row) {

            ?>
            <!-- backeng logic close -->     
               <div class="card-panel light-blue darken-1"><?php echo $row['Question_id'];
                                                                 echo '&nbsp'; 
                                                                 echo $row['question']; 
                                                                 echo '?'
                                                                 ?></div>

                        <p>
                          <label>
                            <input name="group3" type="radio" value="<?php $row['option1'] ?>" />
                            <span><?php echo $row['option1'] ?></span>
                          </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            <input name="group3" type="radio" value="<?php $row['option2'] ?>" />
                            <span><?php echo $row['option2'] ?></span>
                          </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            <input name="group3" type="radio"  value="<?php $row['option3'] ?>" />
                            <span><?php echo $row['option3'] ?></span>
                          </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            <input name="group3" type="radio" value="<?php $row['option4'] ?>" />
                            <span><?php echo $row['option4'] ?></span>
                          </label>
                        </p>

                        <?php

                }

                        ?>
                          <!-- submit button -->
                                <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-content">
                                        <p>
                                          <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('submitValue').disabled = !this.checked;"/>
                                            <span>I agree that, And I'm sure to submit my answers.</span>
                                          </label>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="col s6 offset-s10">
                                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submitValue" disabled type="submit">Submit
                                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                          </button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                          <!-- submit button end      -->
                    </form>
```

But, the problem is, when i'm selecting the radio button, it will not  consider as separate question for every row that returns by foreach() loop..

what is the best way to do that?

thanks in advance...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023698/2469308 let me know if it works for u or not ?

Comment: What dou you mean by that problem about your radio button? Could it help to give the radio button a clear name?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query which fetches questions from the database to:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND();
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comments, to limit the query results to just 15:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: Actually, i have 30 questions in my database table.. And i want to display only 15 random questions from overall 30 questions at once..is there any way?

Comment: Yes, there is, it's called `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rand() for random and limt for limit the rows result

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: yae.. that solves my problem.. but there is another issue , take a look at my question once.. Issue regarding with my radio buttons when displaying questions from database..

Comment: Your are using the same name ( `name="group3"`)  for each row .. if you have 15 rows  you must assign  different name  to each  .. otherwise whe you receive the answer  is like you have a single row only

Comment: Clarify that issue in the question itself and we can help

Comment: how to assign different names for each row that returns from database..can you please ..tell me how to do that?

Comment: you could simply add  a conter to your name (instead of gruop3 .. you could buil a progressiva value)  ..r. but  you should manage a question at a time  .. otherwise is difficult solve you problem  ..

Answer (score 0):

The **RAND()** function returns a random number or a random number within a range.

*The RAND() function will return a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).*

The **RAND()** function will return a completely random number if no seed is provided, and a repeatable sequence of random numbers if a seed value is used.

```
public function loadQuestions() {
   try {
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15');
       $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt;
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Return a random decimal number (**no seed value** - so it returns a completely random number >= 0 and <1):

> SELECT RAND();

Return a random decimal number >= 5 and <10:

> SELECT RAND()*(10-5)+5;

You may also uses the **php mt_rand()** function with query:-

The **mt_rand()** function generates a random integer using the Mersenne Twister algorithm.

*Tip: This function produces a better random value, and is 4 times faster than rand().*

Tip: If you want a random integer between 10 and 100 (inclusive), use mt_rand (10,100).

```
<form action="#">
      <!-- this backend logic -->
        <?php 
             foreach($stmt as $row) {

        echo '
        <!-- backeng logic close -->     
           <div class="card-panel light-blue darken-1"> '.$row['Question_id'].'

                                                              '.$row['question'].'
                                                              ?
                                                             </div>

                    <p>
                      <label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" value=" '.$row['option1'].' " />
                        <span> '.$row['option1'].' </span>
                      </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" value=" '.$row['option2'].'" />
                        <span>'.$row['option2'].' </span>
                      </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio"  value="'.$row['option3'].'" />
                        <span>'.$row['option3'].' </span>
                      </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" value=" '.$row['option4'].' " />
                        <span>'.$row['option4'].' </span>
                      </label>
                    </p>';
                   }

                    ?>
              <!-- submit button -->
                    <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                            <p>
                              <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('submitValue').disabled = !this.checked;"/>
                                <span>I agree that, And I'm sure to submit my answers.</span>
                              </label>
                            </p>
                            <div class="col s6 offset-s10">
                            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submitValue" disabled type="submit">Submit
                                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              <!-- submit button end      -->
        </form>
```